# How are Java 8 method references different from 'real' function pointers?

Tags: java, lambda, closures, function-pointers, java-8

Someone told me tbat Java 8 method references aren't as powerful as 'true' function pointers.

How is it so? How are method references different from function pointers?

Comment: 1) You should ask these questions in separate questions.  2) Function pointers in which language?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is currying?

Currying is the ability to construct a new method reference from an existing method and an argument. e.g.

```
// this is curried and implied in this method.
BiFunction<String, Integer> m = this::methodTwo;

// create a new curried method.
Function<String> m10 = t -> m.apply(t, 10);
```

A real example is a consumer

```
// curry this method so that when called it prints to System.out
Consumer<String> out = System.out::println;
```

> Java 8 method references aren't as powerful as 'true' function pointers.

Java 8 method references are actually a reference to an object which encapsulates a virtual method.  This works very well up to a point, but some basic things you might expect you can't do. e.g. equals(), toString(), expression examination won't do what you might expect.

> How are method references different from function pointers?

A function pointer is purely a reference to a function.  A method reference in Java includes currying information e.g. this a method which has X, Y, Z as know arguments.

> does Java 8 support true closures?

Java tends to be minimalist in terms of features, but you can take it as given than no feature in Java is "pure".  It has too much backward compatibility issues to deal with that even if there was the will to be pure, it couldn't be.

> do we still need to declare a variable final before being able to use it in a lambda?

No, "effectively final" is good enough. i.e. if you could have made it final, it is ok.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: from the programmer's perspecticve, is there a difference between function pointers and method references?

Comment: @Prog the primary difference is that the term is used in different languages. That aside, a "method" implied OO design and you can have implicit references to a "this", in Java you can references to other objects as well. A method doesn't imply that arguments will not be changed.  A "function" implies, all arguments are explicit and unchanged.

Comment: For example, in JS you can assign a function to a variable. In Java 8 you can also do that. How are method references in Java 8 different than function pointers in languages such as JS, C, etc?

Comment: @Prog function pointers in JS and C are very different. ;)  The key difference is implicit arguments or currying. In functional languages, functions imply immutable arguments.

Comment: @Prog JS doesn't have "function pointers"; rather, functions (which are just objects) in JS are *first-class values* from the get-go.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of this question is semantics.  Us old C programmers think of a "pointer" as a "memory address," which in C they are.  Anything just isn't a true "pointer."  But whether that matters that something is or isn't a "true pointer" is a different question.  Mostly it doesn't matter.

Comment: @markspace: I'm asking about the programmer'sperspective - to a programmer, 'method references' are basically 'function pointers', am I right? Or do they have some limitations?

Comment: @Prog That is my perspective, as a programmer.  I've done a LOT of very low-level programming, so I often think in terms of bits and bytes and addresses.  It's best to think of each language as a separate thing.  Worry about what the language spec says and how it works.  Don't compare language features, that's usually madness.

Answer (score 0):

> A method reference is not a new type in Java. **It is not a function
>   pointer as used in some other programming languages.** It is simply
>   shorthand for writing a lambda expression using an existing method. It
>   can only be used where a lambda expression can be used.

Excerpted from: [Java Language Features, Kishori Sharan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484233476)